# How to implement a list with decorated elements

Tags: java, design-patterns, decorator, cdi

Having a result of REST or JPA query I have an often requirement to decorate items with some additional attributes that come from some other queries. To avoid coping and processing the list ( the result ) I am thinking about a runtime universal list decorator that contains items decorated at runtime.

The question: is there any standard pattern for that?

Example: as a result of REST query I have list of people. I need to decorate each person with vacation quota.

I searched occasionally for such pattern for many years but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I created two clases to implement this:

```
@Dependent
public abstract class ElementDecorator<E> {
    public abstract void wrap( E elem );
}
```

and

```
@Dependent
public class MyList<E extends ElementDecorator> extends AbstractList {
    
    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog( this.getClass() );
    private List list;
    private Class<E> clazz;
    private Annotation annotation;
    
    public MyList(){}
    
    public MyList( List oryList, Class<E> c ){
        list = oryList;
        clazz = c;
    }
    
    public MyList( List oryList, Class<E> c, Annotation a ){
        list = oryList;
        clazz = c;
        annotation = a;
    }
    
    @Override
    public E get( int index ){
        if( annotation == null )
            annotation = new AnnotationLiteral<Default>() {};
        E element = null;
        try{
            element = CDI.current().select( clazz, annotation ).get();
            element.wrap( list.get( index ) );
        }catch( Exception e ){
            log.error( e.getMessage() );
        }
        return element;
    }
    
    public int size(){
        return list.size();
    }

}
```

Now whenever I need a list of decorated elements I extend ElementDecorator with:

```
@Dependent
@Default
public class AppointmentDecorator extends ElementDecorator<Appointment> implements Serializable {
    
    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog( this.getClass() );
    private @Inject SmCostDao smCostDao;
    private Appointment appointment;
    
    @Override
    public void wrap( Appointment a ){
        appointment = a;
    }
    
    public Appointment getAppointment(){
        return appointment;
    }
    
    public String getCostCorrected(){
        SmCost smcost = smCostDao.findBy(appointment.getKey());
        smcost.getCost();
    }
    
}
```

and I can instantiate: MyList( oryginalList, AppointmentDecorator )